# socket.io + using 'emit' with a callback?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having an issue with my sockets where my server side code is executing before my `socket.emit` finishes. Here's a snippet:

```
admin.getTh(function(th){
   socket.emit('GPS', {gpsResults: data, thresholds: th, PEMSID: PEMSID, count: count});
   count++;
   toolbox.drawPaths(function(ta){
        console.log(ta);
   });
});
```

So what I need to have happen is the code that gets executed on the client via `socket.emit('GPS', ...)` to completely finish before `toolbox.drawPaths` happens. I tried to toss a callback on the `emit` like you would `socket.on(..., function(){...})` but that doesn't seem to be part of the API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you might want to do is create an event on the server that gets emitted when your GPS is completed.

For example:

**Server**

```
socket.on ('GPS', function (data) {
  // Do work

  // Done doing work
  socket.emit ('messageSuccess', data);
});
```

**Client**

```
socket.emit('GPS', {gpsResults: data, thresholds: th, PEMSID: PEMSID, count: count});
socket.on ('messageSuccess', function (data) {
  //do stuff here
  toolbox.drawPaths(function(ta){
    console.log(ta);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes that's what I've been looking at doing now, for some reason the array on the client side is still empty when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I don't know the specified context of the array you're talking about, but I would make sure it is created initially and it exists before it's sent to you

Comment: So, does that mean that callbacks not supported in emit function in Socket.IO?